# PHP loop - poor SQL performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo, mariadb

I'm looping through 40 associative arrays:

```
array(
  'key0' => value,
  'url0' => value,
  'tit0' => value,
  'cdn0' => value,
  'cdn1' => value,
  'cdn2' => value,
)
```

and I am performing multiple `select` and one *possible* `insert` queries. I tried to optimize the performance by reducing the amount of queries.

```
foreach($buf){
  $sth1->execute();//SELECT * FROM metadata WHERE url = '{$buf['url0']}'
  $sth2->execute();//SELECT * FROM metadata WHERE key = '{$buf['key0']}'

  if(!$ret=$sth1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if($sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      die( 'key duplicate - error' );
    }

    $data[ ] = $buf;

    $sth3->execute();//INSERT INTO metadata ...
  } else {
    $data[ ] = $ret; 
}
```

This is however slow (the loop takes about 4.2 seconds). I tried making it faster by removing a query.

```
foreach($buf){
  $sth1->execute();//SELECT * FROM metadata WHERE url = '{$buf['url0']}' OR key = '{$buf['key0']}'

  if(!$ret=$sth1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){       
    $sth3->execute();//INSERT INTO metadata ...

    $data[ ] = $buf;
  } else {
    if($ret['key']==$generated_key){die('key duplicate - error');}

    $data[ ] = $ret; 
}
```

This for some reason made it even slower (5-6s). Thus, I'm left clueless. How can I make this have a reasonable load time? I tried putting `$sth2->execute` in the `if(!$ret...)` statement but that doesn't give me any speed gain either.

It doesn't seem to be the `INSERT` that is the problem due to most of the `array` data being already `IN` the database. Whenever I run queries in phpmyAdmin it does it in 0.0000000003 seconds so it must have something to do with the loop.

Comment: I would try using one transaction for all the inserts. It changes the amount of work the database has to do and when it does it. Start the ''transaction' before your `foreach loop` and close it after. Be aware. any errors then all 40 inserts will need to be done again.

Comment: Done. Slight speed increase. (.2s). Thank you.

Comment: hmm... that is disappointing.  I would suggest 'explain plan' and  timing the query to see where it is spending the time. I would also consider 'preparing' the  queries before the 'foreach' loop.

Comment: @RyanVincent Some queries only have to do about two inserts, so the problem does not lie there. Preparing them is _already_ done before the foreach loop

Comment: Executing query inside loops reduces performance of your website a lot. If you need to fetch hundreds of rows then your loop will make hundreds of queries.

One way you can avoid this is by mapping array of your `where` credentials and perform a single query using `WHERE IN` outside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speedup #1:  Move `$sth2->execute();` to right after the first `if`.  You don't seem to need the result if the `url` test succeeds.

Speedup #2:  Be sure to have `INDEX(url)` and `INDEX(key)`;

Speedup #3:  Change `INDEX(key)` to `UNIQUE(key)` and skip the `SELECT ... key`; simply check for dup key after doing the `INSERT`.

Speedup #4:  (This one may or may not help.)  Do all of the `SELECT ... url` in a single query:  `SELECT ... url IN (40-urls-in-list)`.  (Requires Speedup #2.)  Save the results in an associative array and walk through it to do the rest of your SELECT/INSERT stuff.

Speedup #5:  Build a 'batch' `INSERT` (multiple rows in a *single* `INSERT`), then `execute` it at the end of the 40-item loop.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

MyISAM? or InnoDB?  Have you tuned innodb_buffer_pool_size to be about 70% of available RAM?  If not, this might improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Is what you considered that possibility?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: It will be helpfull if you add some explanations here and give the reference. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not enough information about your MySQL indexing strategy or amount of information you select.

Possible issues that come to my mind in first second:

- when you perform queries from MySQL you hit query cache, from loop cache is at some point expired
- poor indexing strategy in database - selection by varchar is not always best solution, using char(16) and MD5 sum (or something similar) is probably is a bit better approach
- you have some unnoticed loop in iterations

Solution to all those would be to echo a lot of debug data with precision timestamp, read them over and log SQL queries to MySQL server log and run all these in one batch in console/PHPMyAdmin for better debugging.